# Testing if a pattern is 'skewed'

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, function

I am running individual-based simulation and I record a statistic over space. This statistic is always zero at the two extremes of the space but display a bump somewhere in the middle. Here is an example of actual data:

```
w=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0056, 0.0092, 0.0088, 0.0152, 0.0108, 0.012, 0.012, 0.0032, 0.0024, 0, 4e-04, 0.0068, 0.0072, 0.0064, 0.0148, 0.0144, 0.0108, 0.0104, 0.0116, 0.0136, 0.014, 0.0196, 0.0316, 0.0288, 0.0344, 0.0324, 0.0476, 0.0544, 0.056, 0.0676, 0.0644, 0.054, 0.0604, 0.0492, 0.0432, 0.0476, 0.0472, 0.0564, 0.0592, 0.0484, 0.0624, 0.0728, 0.0552, 0.0696, 0.0784, 0.0836, 0.0596, 0.0584, 0.0736, 0.0764, 0.0812, 0.0884, 0.0948, 0.0756, 0.0812, 0.0804, 0.0856, 0.0776, 0.082, 0.0928, 0.0876, 0.1196, 0.106, 0.0968, 0.0864, 0.0912, 0.0788, 0.0604, 0.0664, 0.054, 0.0472, 0.064, 0.0584, 0.0376, 0.0176, 0.0208, 0.0216, 0.0232, 0.0068, 0.0028, 0.0056, 0.01, 0.008, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4e-04, 0.0036, 0.0032, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0.0044, 0.0012, 0.0, 0.0024, 8e-04, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
w = w/sum(w)
x=123:(122+length(w))

plot(y=w,x=x)
```

[image]

If we were looking at a histogram, one would maybe say that it is negatively skewed.

**I would like to perform a statistical test to question whether the observed pattern is "skewed".**

Part of my issue might be in the definition of the question (incl. definition of skew) and part of my issue might be in the method to answer this question.

I am tempted to rescale the values of the statistic `stat` so that it sums to one and consider that the observed pattern as if it was a histogram of a sample of arbitrary size $n$, consider [Pearson skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Pearson.27s_moment_coefficient_of_skewness) as my statistic of interest and use bootstrap to get a pvalue for whether my pattern is skewed.

I am also tempted to search for the normal distribution that best fit the data (e.g. by sum of square of residuals) and call it my null model. Then look for the [skewed normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) that best fit the data, call the alternative model and perform a G-test (or similar tests). However, the data don't really look like a normal (or skewed normal) distribution and the choice of the type of function for the null and alternative model seem very arbitrary. Also, I have many such pattern to test for skewness and they might well differ in their general shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample skewness  $
        = \frac{n}{(n-1)(n-2)} \sum_{i=1}^n (\frac{x_i-\overline{x}}{s})^3,
  $
where $\overline{x}$ is the sample mean, $s$ is the Standard deviation, AKA, the corrected sample standard deviation.

Now, to fit a density distribution to this data, you would have to search for one that has the appropriate ability to be skewed. A normal distribution has zero skewness, so that would not be a good choice. Your best choice might be to use a search algorithm like the [FindDistribution](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistribution.html) routine in Mathematica. There are similar routines in other computer languages as well, one can even do this in Excel.